# Primeng : PickList not showing button icons

Tags: angular, primeng, picklist

i am using picklist in my application but it seems that button icons that is for moving data item from source to target, that icons of arrow is not getting display in my page. it just shows blank buttons. if you select item and clicks on any button it will work as expected but icons are not getting displayed.

```
<p-pickList [source]="availableColumns" [target]="usedColumns" sourceHeader="Available" targetHeader="Used" [responsive]="true" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">
                            <template let-col pTemplate="item">
                                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">                                
                                    <div style="font-size:14px;margin:5px 5px 0 0">{{col.header}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </p-pickList>
```

I m not getting any error on my console.

[image: here is my screenshot]

Comment: please add your code and the error message you are getting.

Comment: edited, please see above, i didn't get any error in my console.

Comment: Hello, i resolved this issue, it was overriding jquery-ui.css ui-button-icon-only class. for now i have removed jqueryui css and its working fine now

Comment: Kamlesh's solution worked for me. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

Did you add font-awesome to your project because primeng uses font-awesome for icons.